# Testing thick client application over citrix

Tags: penetration-test, appsec

I am looking for a checklist or methodologies which can be adopted to test a thick client application over citrix environment. Owasp has listed some top 10 issues to look for in a thick client but as the application is accessible only over citrix environment cannot adopt those straightaway.

Thanks in advance.